# How To Dynamically change Images in kivy?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am trying to Change The background image in the following code to B_image2.png. I tried writing a function that gets called aand change the address of the background Image once I click an image, and it does change the address stored in the B_G_IMG variable but The screen doesnot get updated.

The .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.graphics.instructions import InstructionGroup
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color

import random

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '320')


running = True


class MyWidget(AnchorLayout):

    LOC = []
    for i in range (10):
        LOC.append((random.randint(0,400),random.randint(0,300)))


    B_G_IMG="B_image.png"


    time_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.time_number = str(50)

    def remove_rectangle(self, widget):
        self.grid_layout.remove_widget(widget)
        self.set_level(2)
    def set_level(self,level_num):
        global B_G_ImG
        B_G_IMG = "B_image2.png"
        print B_G_IMG


    def call(self):
        if running:
            #print(self.time_number)
            #self.time_number = str(int(self.time_number)+1)
            pass            
    def clicked(self):
        global running
        #self.time_number = 50
        running=False

    Clock.schedule_interval(call, 1)

    pos1 =(0) #random.randint(-200,200)
    pos2 =(0) #random.randint(-200,200)

class WidgetsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__=="__main__":
    WidgetsApp().run()
```

The .kv file

```
<ImgButton@Button>:

    size_hint:(None,None)
    size:(60,60)

<MyWidget>:
    grid_layout: grid_layout
    AnchorLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            Image:
                source:root.B_G_IMG
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text:root.time_number
        FloatLayout:

            id: grid_layout

            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[0])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[1])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[2])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)    
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[3])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[4])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[5])                   
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[6])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[7])
                background_normal: 'image.png'    
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[8])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[9])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind to kivy properties, not just any python attribute (in this case even a class attribute, which probably isn't what you wanted anyway).

Instead you should declare the property as

```
B_G_IMG = StringProperty("B_image.png")
```

Edit: And remove the global stuff, you should access it with `self.B_G_IMG` from methods of the class.

Also, property names should start with lower case letters as kv language uses this to identify them in rules. In this case it will probably work because you don't set the property in kv, but I recommend sticking to this convention (which is also a pep8 convention) to avoid problems in the future.